# inhomogeneous heat equation with mixed boundary conditons

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Solve $$U_{t}=U_{xx}+u$$ with mixed boundary conditions $$U_x(0,t)=0, U(l,t)=0$$
and initial condition $$U(x,0)=\varphi(x)$$

I know that I have to use separation of variables and I have an idea of how to do it when its either just Dirichlet or just Neumann but both together and with a source I have no idea any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. I helped you with some typesetting. In the long run it's good if you learn some typesetting too as it gets easier for people to read the equations. By the way is $u$ supposed to be the $U$ without any derivative? I could not find any other explanation for it.

Comment: In a first step, without considering the boundary and initial conditions, what do you obtain with the separation of variables ?

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\,\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\partiald{\mrm{U}\pars{x,t}}{t} =
>      \partiald[2]{\mrm{U}\pars{x,t}}{x} + \mrm{u}\pars{x,t}\,,\qquad
> \left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcccl}
> \ds{\left.\partiald{\mrm{U}\pars{x,t}}{x}\,\right\vert_{\ x\ =\ 0}} & \ds{=} &
> \ds{\mrm{U}\pars{L,t}} & \ds{=} &  \ds{0}
> \\[3mm]
> \ds{\mrm{U}\pars{x,0}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\varphi\pars{x}}&&
> \end{array}\right.}$.

---

First, we look for a lineal combination $\ds{A\sin\pars{kx} + B\cos\pars{kx}}$ which satisfies the *homogeneous* boundary conditions at
$\ds{x = 0\ \mbox{and}\ x = L}$.

$\ds{\left.\vphantom{\large A}0 = k\bracks{A\cos\pars{kx} - B\sin{kx}}
\right\vert_{\ x\ =\ 0}\,\,\, =\,\,\, kA}$ is satisfied with $\ds{k = 0}$ or $\ds{A = 0}$. $\ds{k = 0}$ just adds a constant term which vanishes out because $\ds{\mrm{U}\pars{L,t} = 0}$.

$\ds{B\cos\pars{kL} = 0}$ is satisfied whenever
$\ds{k \in W \equiv \braces{\pars{n + \half}\,{\pi \over L}\,,\ n = 0,1,2,\ldots}}$

---

Now, we are ready to write the *general solution* as
$\ds{\mrm{U}\pars{x,t} =
\sum_{k}A_{k}\pars{t}\cos\pars{kx}}$ where $\ds{k \in W}$. It satisfies:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k}\totald{A_{k}\pars{t}}{t}\,\cos\pars{kx} =
-\sum_{k}A_{k}\pars{t}k^{2}\cos\pars{kx} + \mrm{u}\pars{x,t}
\end{equation}
Multiply both sides by $\ds{\cos\pars{qx}}$, where $\ds{q \in W}$, and integrate over $\ds{\pars{0,L}}$:
\begin{equation}
\totald{A_{q}\pars{t}}{t} =
-q^{2}A_{q}\pars{t} + \hat{\mrm{u}}_{q}\pars{t}\,,\qquad
\hat{\mrm{u}}_{q}\pars{t} \equiv
{2 \over L}\int_{0}^{L}\mrm{u}\pars{x,t}\cos\pars{qx}\,\dd x\tag{1}
\end{equation}
Also,
\begin{equation}
\varphi\pars{x} = \mrm{U}\pars{x,0} =
\sum_{k}A_{k}\pars{0}\cos\pars{kx}\quad\imp\quad
A_{k}\pars{0} =
{2 \over L}\int_{0}^{L}\varphi\pars{x}\cos\pars{kx}\,\dd x
\tag{2}
\end{equation}

---

Eqtn. $\ds{\pars{1}}$ is easily solved:
\begin{align}
\totald{\bracks{\exp\pars{q^{2}\, t}A_{q}\pars{t}}}{t} & =
\exp\pars{q^{2}\, t}\hat{\mrm{u}}_{q}\pars{t}\,,\qquad
\pars{~A_{k}\pars{0}\ \mbox{is given by}\ \pars{2}~}
\\[5mm] \imp
A_{q}\pars{t} & =
A_{q}\pars{0}\exp\pars{-q^{2}\, t} +
\int_{0}^{t}\exp\pars{-q^{2}
\pars{t - \tau}}\hat{\mrm{u}}_{q}\pars{\tau}\,\dd\tau
\\
& \hat{\mrm{u}}_{q}\pars{\tau}\ \mbox{is given in}\ \pars{1}.
\end{align}

---

The $\ds{\underline{final\ solution}}$ which satisfies the conditions at the top is given by:
\begin{align}
\color{#66f}{\mrm{U}\pars{x,t}} & =
\color{#66f}{\sum_{q}\bracks{A_{q}\pars{0}\exp\pars{-q^{2}\, t} +
\int_{0}^{t}\exp\pars{-q^{2}
\pars{t - \tau}}\hat{\mrm{u}}_{q}\pars{\tau}\,\dd\tau}\cos\pars{qx}}\,,\quad
q \in W
\\[5mm]
A_{q}\pars{0} & = {2 \over L}\int_{0}^{L}\varphi\pars{x}\cos\pars{qx}\,\dd x
\,,\qquad
\hat{\mrm{u}}_{q}\pars{t} \equiv
{2 \over L}\int_{0}^{L}\mrm{u}\pars{x,t}\cos\pars{qx}\,\dd x\,,\quad
q \in W
\end{align}

Comment: I don't understand why this hasn't received any up vote ... until now, +1.